# pushViewController pushes but no view change

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

When I try to push a `UIViewController` subclass (`MissionViewController`) onto a `UINavigationController` from within my root view controller, the `viewDidLoad` method is only called if I reference the underlying view after initializing the view controller.  However, even with the method called, the screen is not updated.

Both the view controller and the navigation controller are not nil.  The file owner in `MissionView.xib` is set to `MissionViewController`.  The view property of the file owner points to the nib view. I've verified that the `topViewController` property of the navigation controller points to the `MissionViewController` object.

If I change `MissionViewController` to be the root view controller, the view loads fine.  Saw several similar posts but still having problems.

**rootViewController.h**

```
@interface TreeGraphController : UIViewController 
{
    MissionViewController *missionViewCtrlr;
}
@property(nonatomic, retain) MissionViewController *missionViewCtrlr;
```

**rootViewController.m**

```
#import "MissionViewController.h"
...
if (!missionViewCtrlr)
{
    MissionViewController *ctrlr = [[MissionViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MissionView" bundle:nil];
    ctrlr.view.hidden = NO;
    self.missionViewCtrlr = ctrlr;
    [ctrlr release];
}

myAppDelegate *del = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
[del.navigationController pushViewController:missionViewCtrlr animated:NO];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about using

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:missionViewCtrlr];
```

in the `rootViewController`? I assume `rootViewController` has been pushed to a `UINavigationController` and that the navigation controller's view was added as a subview of self.window in the app delegate?

Btw, you may simplify part of your code by just saying

```
if(!missionViewCtrlr)
  self.missionViewCtrlr = [[MisionViewController alloc] init...];
```

Comment: Thanks, the wrong subview had been added to self.window (from root view controller instead of the navigation controller).  Re: simplification, I've found that clang in xcode 4.1 gives false leak warnings if I don't explicitly release.

Comment: No problem. Re: Simplification, you still have to release it explicitly, but you need to do so in dealloc. Actually, you would still have to release missionviewCtrlr in dealloc even if you use your code above... self.missionviewCtrlr is a retain property.

Comment: Even with the release in dealloc, clang still complains if there's not an explicit release statement in the method with the alloc.  Hopefully, this will change in the future.  I know I'm introducing unnecessary complexity, but it sure feels nice to have that false sense of security that comes from a lack of clang warnings :-). However, I do prefer to handle all warnings so I don't miss any true problems it catches.